# which kind of phonetic symbol is it?

Tags: phonetics, phonetic-symbols

I read a electric dictionary in which the phonetic symbol are descirbed in the weird form.
For example:

> afar
>   / E5fB:(r); E`fBr/

which kind of phonetic symbol is it? Is there a full mapping list to normal phonetic symbol?

Comment: I would guess that they're using a non Unicode IPA font, so now it just looks like random letters.

Comment: It looks like a machine-readable ASCII transcoding of IPA in which E=ə, B=ɑ and 5 or ` is a stress indicator. Anybody recognize it?

Answer (score 4):

[I found a copy of the PDF](http://docsplayer.com/25363210-4d-f736f-f-d20c1f5d2bbc4d0cdd0b8a3e1dbb7e5b4cabbe-a1aabbf9b4a1b4cabbe3b2bfb7d6a3a8c8aba3a92e646f63.html) available for download by selecting the Download tab and passing the CAPTCHA.

It's probably a widely pirated English lesson from [koolearn](http://www.koolearn.com/), which other websites copied and pasted without taking care of the IPA symbols.

The following is the full mapping. There are other symbols between brackets but they appear as is in the PDF, not mapped by the braindead font.

```
5   ˈ
7   ˌ
9   ˌ
:   ː
?@  ＵＳ
A   æ
B   ɑ
C   ɔ
E   ə
F   ʃ
I   ɪ
J   ʊ
L   ɚ
N   ŋ
Q   ʌ
R   ɔ
T   ð
U   u
V   ʒ
W   θ
Z   ɛ
\   ɜ
^   ɡ
```

Answer (score 2):

Searching for the text, I found [this Web page](http://en.cshu.org/s/a/95). Here's a screenshot:

[image: afar]

The document refers OED, and here's [OED's page for *afar*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/afar):

> afar
>   Pronunciation: /əˈfɑː/

So, it just seems that cshu.org has incorrectly imported phonetic representation from electronic version of OED.

Case closed. :)

Comment: This ASCII coding also appears in a Korean source which seems to be drawn from *OALD* - see [en.eywedu.net/tools/zw3], located by DamkerngT on ELU. But I don't think the case is quite "closed"; OP also asks for a "full mapping list".